# Why are pattern variables also renamed in macro expansion?

Tags: scheme, racket

While reading Dybvig's paper *Syntactic Abstraction in Scheme*, I noticed that the algorithm also renames pattern variables.  So it means pattern variables may cause capture.  But I have no idea in what case they would cause capture?  Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro can expand into a macro definition using patterns. Pattern variables have lexical scope just as normal variables, so they need to be renamed too.

Example of macro expanding into macro definition.

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax (define-get/put-id stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id get put!)
     #'(define-syntax id
         (syntax-id-rules (set!)
           [(set! id e) (put! e)]
           [(id a (... ...)) ((get) a (... ...))]
           [id (get)]))]))

(define id 0)
(set! id 42)
(define-get/put-id clock 
  (λ()  (displayln "Reading clock") id)
  (λ(x) (displayln "Setting clock") (set! id x) id))

clock
(set! clock 10)
clock

;;; Output
Reading clock
42
Setting clock
10
Reading clock
10
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks.  But a simpler example than shows how capture occurs would be more helpful.  Also, the case for `(id a (... ...))` does not work.  A call like `(clock 1 2 3)` causes error.